# Drag and drop file from browser to email attachments

Tags: javascript, html, activex

I'm currently struggling with a request from a user

**The request from the user is as follows:**

-You should be able to attach a file (in my case a PDF file) to your email with drag and drop

-You should not have to manually save the file to your computer

-The PDF file should automatically be placed into the Email attachments once you drop it there

-If there are other similar ways to do the same. (Doesn't have to be with Drag and Drop, it can also work with a menu button or something like that

-Plugins could also be used

-The browser used is IE 11

I know this request is quite unique but I would like to implement this feature.

Many thanks in advance ^^

Attempts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
 <script>
var files = document.querySelectorAll('.dragout');
for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) {
file.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
e.dataTransfer.setData('DownloadURL', this.dataset.downloadurl);
}, false);
}
</script>
    <title>PDF Drag and Drop</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
PDF DnD with Javascript
<p>
<a href="Speiseplan.pdf" class=".dragout" data-downloadurl="application/pdf:Chrome3DGlasses.pdf::http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/intl/en/landing/chrome/cadie/glasses.pdf"&gt;.pdf file>
HTML Referenz als PDF
</a>
<p>
<embed width="600" height="600" src="Speiseplan.pdf">
<p>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: please specify what you have try to achieve... no one is here to solve your homework...

Comment: What I have tried?

Comment: yes you need to share something that you are tried..

Comment: Well mostly I have tried to find a way. I didnt write much code atm. I searched for plugins and though of concepts. I also had some attempts with javascript. I also didnt find any similar problems online. So I came here to ask for help

Comment: is there a away to add code in the comments? it just says "comment to long"

Comment: no try to update your question

Comment: okay so u updated it

Comment: did you tried gmail api `https://ctrlq.org/code/20132-gmail-api-send-mail-attachments`

Comment: Uh seems nice, gonna try it thank you ^^ is there something similar for outlook?

Comment: I don't know about outlook I think there is let me check ..